# If your phone is rooted, can it still do normal factory reset?

Tags: rooting, factory-reset

Like you wouldn't notice if it's rooted or not?

Comment: A factory reset won't necessarily return `/system` to its original state, so likely will not un-root or undo other changes like uninstalling system apps.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but unrooting will require more than a simple factory reset. The process will depend on your phone model. Search your model and 'unroot' for instructions. Be sure the instructions are for your specific model and are from a trustworthy source, such as XDA. But if you were able to root your device, I assume you already know that.

Answer (score 0):

It may factory reset the apps,etc to normal settings. But in some rooted phones certain aspects of the OS remain changed. I.E. system programs inserted by manual or automatic rooting of phone, Kingroot is one rooting program I have found that stays persistent in ROM.

Also, if you remove any system apps as I have done you may have issues even booting up a "non bricked" phone. See this for example, [How to F up a phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/119467/rooted-phone-missing-key-features-help/)