# Rooted phone missing key features, help!

Tags: rooting, factory-reset, 5.1-lollipop, menu

I have a new MetroPCS Lg Leon running lollypop 5.02. I rooted it with kingroot apk (bad idea) and I cannot get the menu bar or swipe gestures to work. I.e. swipe to search,  there is no pull down menu.

I must have messed with some settings in root but I factory reset the phone multiple times and hot reset it if that is any different with the battery out. Not corrected.

The lg startup screen starts each time I boot it as well.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer. I had to give the android system full root privledges and/or unroot. It updated as it should to a new version of lollypop in a few days time. Any better answer please post.